# sorting out pensions on death

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, inheritance, death

My mother passed away about 14 months ago. She had 3 pensions that are going to pay a lump sum out due to her death, she died before pensionable age. She nominated me and my two brothers to be the beneficiaries of these pensions in the event of her death.

However, the way things have been handled by the solicitor up until now is starting to smell fishy to me.

My questions are

1) how long does it usually take for pensions to be sorted out upon someone's death. It's been over a year and we still have no idea how much longer it's going to take our what the delay is. Could be the pension companies, could be the solicitor. What is the usual timeframe ?

We are in the UK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any personal experience of actually claiming them, but in the UK lump sum pension benefits are normally paid direct by the pension company to the beneficiaries rather than going through the estate of the deceased. This means they don't need to go through probate or inheritance tax, and should be payable pretty quickly.

So even if you have a solicitor dealing with the estate, she or he may not be actively involved in claiming the lump sum. If you haven't already contacted the pension company directly, you should do so now.